# java Restful web application and WADL

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, wadl

In SOAP we have to provide wsdl to Client . But in Rest what we have to share with the client ? As per my thinking for pure restful web services we don't need to have any documentation(wadl) then what we will give to the client ?

Comment: API document for the rest services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create/generate the API documentation for your API and provide to client.

You can use tools to do that and this link may help you: [automated-documentation-rest-apis](http://www.programmableweb.com/news/automated-documentation-rest-apis/2012/03/28)

and this also: [How do you document your APIs?](http://www.infoq.com/research/api-documentation)

Comment: that means we need wadl . but a pure restful webservices dont need any documentation

Comment: @PRIYANKSINHA .. yes WADL may be helpful but documentation is more kind of self explanatory and may be with examples. API documentation is much easier to read/understand than WADL.

Comment: @PRIYANKSINHA .. for example you can look at [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public)

Comment: @PRIYANKSINHA .. is this resolve your query or you have more on this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply . As per you  sharing of documentation with self explanatory and example is better then WADL .

Comment: your twitter example is open for all , any one can use this REST services . IN case there is some REST services which we don't want to post it in public but we want to give only to some specific client , in these case how we can restrict the client to only valid client , what we will give to that specific valid  client

Comment: @priyanksinha... Rest authentication is separate topic. You will have single documentation for all and then documentation will tell the how to validate yourself. Only allowed users will be able to access the service.